# Port Java Application to Android

Tags: java, android, linux, jar, port

I am not so sure about the question or what I should call what I am trying to achieve.
I use a dialer called super sify. Here is the download - http://thegoan.com/supersify/supersify.zip
The when extracted it has two files for linux, one is a .jar file which consists of some classes. The application was written in java. The other is a .sh file, which is a shell executable and takes some parameters like username and password and machine id and stuff. 
I want to port this app to android. What exactly would I have to do.
 Some more information is the .jar file is named supersify.jar
and the .sh file is named ss.sh so here is the code for ss.sh

```
java -jar supersify.jar $*
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then read
fi
```

Please help me out. This is an open source software.So I am not doing any illegal modifications. 
I need to port this app to android, so would I have to write the whole thing again or just something else. I know some basic hello world android app development, and I have made an app to add two numbers, I am still on my way to become an android app developer, but I need this app and will learn a lot to make this possible unless it involves rewriting all the java classes. 
Thank you in advance
If you have anymore question I will be glad to answer to them :D.

Comment: "What exactly would I have to do" is **way** beyond the scope of a StackOverflow question.

Comment: "SuperSify has been written in Java and will work on Windows, Linux and the Mac" & you can't make it run on Android unless you rewrite / replace a lot of java

Comment: I think you will have a hard time porting the app, a lot of the java libraries are not compatible or have been overridden in Android, so you are likely to get compiler or dependency errors.

Answer (score 2):

The approach is straight forward:

- Create a new Android project, e.g. with the Android plugin for Eclipse
- Add the Jar file to the project.
- Create an Android main Activity as with any other Android project
- Look at the jar file to determine what its default `main` method is (In the manifest, or just search for the static method `main` in the classes in the Jar file and have a guess)
- Call that main method from your main Activity. Hardcode the parameters or create a dialog to get them from the user, or something similar.
- The shell script seems to read a line from stdin if the main method returns 1. Not sure why it does that if it does not use this line, but in case it makes some sense do the same in your main Activity based on the `main` method return value.

As others pointed out this will not work if the Jar file uses classes which exist in standard java but not in Android. Since most classes are the same your chances are generally good.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully compile the app for android.

please refer:
source code: https://github.com/mayurdange/supersify
apk: http://db.tt/KE9kqpo6